# Question about Unity Serialization public array class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I just new to serialization, and have a question why the public array 
 of custom class does not show up on inspector.

let's say I have code like follow

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class A:MonoBehaviour{

    public B b;

    public C[] c= new C[3];

    public D d;
    public E[] e;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {    
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class D
{
}
// Same goes for this you can remove monobehaviour
[System.Serializable]
public class E
{
}
```

I found that variable 'b' is on inspector in unity but I couldn't find where 'c' is.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html

As far as I know, I don't need to do [Serializefield] or [Serializable] public variables both a and b to show up inspector(because both are public, must automatically show up on inspector(?)).

Can anyone explain to me why 'c' does not appear on the inspector? Or am I miss-understand something? Any explanation would be appreciated.

---

Here is B and C class. Same code just name difference.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class B: MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class C: MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I tried D,C suggested below answer. and both not shows up on the inspector.

Comment: what type is `A` and `B` and is `C` really a `MonoBehaviour` (in that case `Serializable` is not required as MonoBehaviour already is serializable)?

Comment: @derHugo oh that [System.Serializable] part above class C is added because kaynn suggested below. I'm not sure about what type means here but A, B and C are same. And I didnt add [System.Serializable] part on A,B though.

Comment: You do not by any chance have a custom editor somewhere for `A` or `MonoBehaviour`, right? Are there any compiler errors in the console preventing that your scripts are re-compiled? Otherwise I see no clue in your posted code why the fields should not appear in the Inspector... Except ofcourse as already said ... None of `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` have any fields so I would not expect to `D` and `E` to show up at all (since there is nothing to serialize) but `B` and `C` should as they are `MonoBehaviour`

Comment: @derHugo I'm so sorry... I keep looking at my A.cs inspector. I found that all variable exists in A gameobject inspector. I'll delete the question If I need to so embarrassing XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Attach this to gameobject and your classes will show up on inspector
public class A : MonoBehaviour
{
    // both B and C is class
    public B b;
    public C[] c;

}

//This doesn't need to be monobehaviour as this should be the data class and A should be the container
[System.Serializable]
public class C {
    public int number;

}
// Same goes for this you can remove monobehaviour
[System.Serializable]
public class B {

   [SerializeField]
    private int ID;

    public string name;

}
```

Comment: I tried this but even 'b' would not show up in the inspector... 'c' did not show up as well

Comment: Nothing will show up until there are serializable fields in your classes (`public` or marked with `[SerializeField] private`)!

Comment: Could you please add your complete code .. it is hard without seeing the real structure of your classes

Comment: @Distance1922 I have updated the code now. now you can see the actual fields in the unity inspector

Comment: @derHugo I'm SO SORRY guys. I keep looking at my A.cs inspector. I found that all variable exists in A gameobject

Comment: @SyedMunimRaza I'm SO SORRY guys. I keep looking at my A.cs inspector. I found that all variable exists in A gameobject

Comment: @Distance1922 I am glad you got it eventually. Great Job !

Answer (score 0):

[Serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) in your current case is about making the object "readable" for the unity's inspector.

When you apply a `Serializable` attribute, it means you are saying that *Objects of this type* can be 'readed' by the unity's inpector.

When you apply a `Serializefield` attribute, it means that you are making the *current object* 'readable' by the inspector.
(Provided that it can be serialized, and it wasn't already serialized in the first place)

Back to your issue, you should mark `C` with a `Serializable` Attribute in your case.
(Though most of the time I find that I don't need to)

Like so:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class C {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!. I just tried to put [System.Serializable] on C class and it still does not show up on the inspector. Just curious, I didn't write [System.Serializable] on B class but it shows up on the inspector. Isn't this because I declare b as public? If so why c wouldn't show up on the inspector <- this was what I curious about.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show your code for class `C`?

Comment: I added it!, but it is just basic script. I'm not sure that helps you :(

Answer (score 0):

Derive your class `A` from `MonoBehaviour` and attach it to a GameObject in the inspector.

Comment: Not every class has to be a `MonoBehaviour` .. if it doesn't provide any behavior but is just a container for data that isn't directly related to a specific GameObject a "normal" class or maybe a `ScriptableObject` is often better

Comment: I tried and variable 'b' disappeared from inspector, 'c' also not show up..

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem that the question has, but just in case someone else runs into it like I did, here's another tip.

Make sure that the array field you would like to serialize is NOT a property. For whatever reason, it doesn't seem to like serializing properties.

```
public class A : MonoBehaviour
{
    // works fine (so long as B meets the conditions mentioned by others)
    public B[] SomeBees;
    
    // does NOT work. do not do.
    public B[] MoreBees { get; set; }
}
```

##### Edit

It appears that the reason properties don't serialize well is because they're literally not supported as stated [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html).

> The serialization system can do the following:
>
> - CAN serialize public non-static fields (of serializable types)
> - CAN serialize nonpublic non-static fields marked with the SerializeField attribute.
> - CANNOT serialize static fields.
> - CANNOT serialize properties.